# How do I access the WF 4 Receive activity from WcfTestClient

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

My workflow needs to wait for either an email approval via Bookmark or a WCF approval via Receive, so I used a Parallel activity. The email approval works just fine but I am trying to test the WCF and cant figure out what URL to use in WCF test client to access the Workflow.

I would be grateful for any leads because I am very new to WCF and am not very sure how to go about solving this problem.

[image: The parallel part of my workflow]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using workflow service and then your second receive activity must be correlate with your first one and cancreateinstance check box set to false and service contract  name is same as first one.

When you generate proxy for the workflow service, operation method is available for call from client.

You can refer this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50820/Establishing-Correlation-Between-Multiple-RECEIVE